# Clicking macro button is giving new name to sheet everytime

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a automated tracker for work related data management. I have one sheet which contains all the button out of which the below is associated with the arrange macro.

```vb
Sub Arrange() 

    Sheets("Consolidated Sheet").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Invoked Function", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = KMIP_Cleanup(Query2)" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Arranged Links", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Arranged_Data(#""Invoked Function"")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Invoked Function"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Invoked Function]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Invoked_Function"
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Arranged Links"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Arranged Links]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Arranged_Links"
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False        
    End With

    Sheets("Macros").Select
    Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Every time I click the button it creates two new sheets which is what I want but on the other hand it gives random name like *Sheet 21* and *Sheet 22*. And after deleting it and re-running it will give *Sheet 23* and *Sheet 24*. I want to give defined name to these sheets.

Comment: Every worksheet has a `.Name` property. You may also have a look on [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/17172829)

Answer (score 1):

As commented, heed the recommendations in linked posted, [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1422451), where multiple answers advise not to use `.Select`, `.Activate`, `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet` and all is variants due to implicit reference, context dependence, runtime errors, performance, and reproducibility.

Instead, for your use case explicitly assign objects with `Set` operator. Then adjust or call the needed underlying properties and methods of object:

```vb
Dim wks As Worksheet
...

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wks.Name = "MySheet1"

With wks.ListObjects.Add
   ...
End With


Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wks.Name = "MySheet2"

With wks.ListObjects.Add
   ...
End With
```